# MaximumInsertCommitSize optimization

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a simple ssis ETL moving data from one server to another, a couple of the tables are 150gb+. For these larger tables how do I optimize the `MaximumInsertCommitSize`, on the server that is being loaded, I see the the the ram utilization is near 100% (64 gb) for the duration of the load for these tables. I am also getting pageiolatch_ex suspensions on the server that is being loaded.

This leads me to believe that the `MaximumInsertCommitSize` needs to be brought down.

my first question is whether you agree with this?

my other questions are more open ended

How do I optimize it by trial and error when it takes an hour to load the table (and table size matters for this operation so I would have to load all of it) ?

would network speed ever play into this optimization due to the increased bandwidth with multiple ?partitions? of data 
would the hard drive speed affect it as this is the servers cheapest component (facepalm) - my thinking here is page io latch memory waits indicate that the number of disk operation is minimized but since the ram is over utilized sending tasks to the drive instead of waiting would be better.

Finally is there a calculator for this, I feel that even vague approximation  of `MaximumInsertCommitSize` would be great *(just based on network, disk, ram, file size, with assumptions that the destination is partitioned and has ample disk space)*